# Conditional SimpleXML possible?

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

I am pulling content from an XML file with SimpleXML.

I was wondering if it is possible to display a certain node depending on the contents of the node, e.g.

```
<article>
    <title>PHP</title>
    <content>yada yada yada</content>
</article>

<article>
    <title>JAVASCRIPT</title>
    <content>yodo yodo yodo</content>
</article>
```

Can SimpleXML find a specific title and then display the article for that title?

Display article whose title is 'PHP'.

I really hope this is possible.

Thanks to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an XPath expression like `//article[title='PHP']/content`

Answer (score 3):

```
$article_list = new SimpleXMLElement($article_xml);
foreach($article_list->article as $i => $article) {
    if('PHP' == $article->title) {
        //code to display article.
    }
}
```

This is assuming the article tags are in a parent element.

Answer (score 3):

See [PHP DevCenter](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/01/15/simplexml.html), here is a sample:

```
$article_list = new SimpleXMLElement($article_xml);  
foreach ($article_list->xpath("//article[title='PHP']/content") as $content) { 
    print "$content\n";
}
```

Also if you know the exact location of the article nodes it is better to avoid the `//` notation which will search in all levels of the XML.